# Создание БД через написание EntityBeans

Tags: java

Доброго всем времени суток!

Вопрос животрепещущий. Помогите кто чем может.)
Изучаю JavaEE (EJB, ORM, Persistence) вторую неделю, поэтому прошу прощения, если ошибаюсь в чем-то.

Есть jBoss 7 Final, Oracle, Eclipse + JBossTools и начальник.
Так вот мне начальник сказал: "Создай Entity Beans (Employee и Department) в проекте в Eclipse (EJBProject) вместе с EAR-ником и задеплой все это jboss-ом  и у тебя будут две таблички в Oracl-е".

Собственно сам бин (только один):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Departments")
public class Department implements Serializable
{
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="department")
    private Set<Employee> employeeSet;

    public Department()
    {
        employeeSet = new HashSet<Employee>();
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="DEP_ID")
    public Long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId( Long id )
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="DEP_NAME")
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName( String name )
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Так вот же третий день сижу, деплою, а воз и ныне там. Ничего в Oracl-е нет.

Возникает сильное ощущения, что начальник неправ.

Так ли это, уважаемые? Или я ошибаюсь (дайте совет) = )

Comment: да, забыл написать, что в standalone.xml драйвер и датасоурс прописаны как полагается, и в modules закинут сам драйвер к oracle (если конечно это имеет смысл в контексте моего топика)

Comment: таблицы сами собой в БД не появятся

Comment: я вот не понимаю, как он мог это сказать. ведь прежде же нужно хотя бы БД создать хотя бы, а потом уже таблички рисовать.

т.е. я прав, думая, что ТОГДА И ТОЛЬКО ТОГДА, КОГДА есть БД (с таблицами), можно рисовать entity и и в них отображать содержимое таблиц, или через них модифицировать данные?

Comment: да
обычно в проекте есть файлики *.sql где лежат скрипты для создания БД, таблиц,..

Comment: У меня таки получилось создать таблички!!! Сменил версию jBoss с 7-ой на 6-ю, создал отдельный файл postgres-ds.xml и все правильно прописал в persistence.xml. Правда щас уже делал на Intellij IDEA 12.1.6